# Rails precompile error in coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, precompile

**In ruby 1.9.3 + rails 3.2.8**

a.js.coffee

```
//= require b_js_file
```

then `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` work!

**But ruby 2.0.0 + rails 3.2.8**

`bundle exec rake assets:precompile` generates :

```
rake aborted!
SyntaxError: unexpected =
  (in /home/me/tmp_code/boot/app/assets/javascripts/a.js.coffee)
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:47:in `rescue in block in call'
 ...
```

when i changed it back to ruby-1.9.3, it worked!

**Why???**

thx!

Answer (score 0):

are you sure there are no blank lines before your statement?
rails expects your delaration to be something like this:

```
//= require file
//= require file
//= require file
//= require file
//= require file
```

this won't work:

```
//= require file
//= require file
//= require file
//
//= require file
```

also this won't work

```
//= require file
//= require file
//= require file

//= require file
```

Comment: In application.js, it has a blank line which likes the Three. But a js file does not have! However, I want to know why is difference from ruby-1.9.3 and ruby-2.0.0.

Comment: I also get the error from practice company 's code. ruby2 gets error, but ruby1.9.3 not!